# Designing client (thick) / server + extra REST API for the thin client

Tags: c++, web-services, rest, client-server

I am redesigning the old application--better to say designing the new application for which I want to take some parts of the old application to be more useful and extendable in future.

The old application is a desktop thick application that works on data shared on a file server. (It uses DBF database free tables, but the design is not client-server -- just a thick application.)

The new application is planned to use the **client-server** architecture with **thick client**, but the server should **also** provide the functionality through the **REST** API interface.

How a specific application server should be designed to be attachable both to a thick client, and to the web service?

The implementation should be portable (Windows, Linux), and also the web server should be or IIS (Microsoft) or a portable web server (like nginx, or so). The implementation language is C++11 plus (at least for the application server, and the thick client).

I am starting from scratch, and I also need to learn the technologies. (I do have experience with C++, and some theoretical knowledge on client-server, and RESTful; however, I need to learn the practical things.)

Comment: consider google protocol buffers for the message encoding and decoding. Version 3 supports both json and binary encoding. It also has stubs for RPC, which you'll find useful.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Thanks for the information!

Comment: @RichardHodges: Please, copy your comment as the answer, so that I can accept or upvote. (There may be more answers as the question is broad. If asking detailed question, I will link it from here.) Reading about Protocol Buffers, I have found also the information about gRPC (http://www.grpc.io/). Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: sure, done. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment as answer, as requested:

Consider google protocol buffers for the message encoding and decoding. Version 3 supports both json and binary encoding. It also has stubs for RPC, which you'll find useful.